# .htaccess subdomains redirect is not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

Ok, now I am lost.

I am trying to do a simple .htaccess redirect of subdomains to a specific folder on the server, meaning all

```
subdomain.mywebsite.com
```

will go to

```
www.mywebsite.com/s_subdomain
```

But for some reasons this doesn't work.

I have tried a lot of settings in .htaccess but for no good. Now in my .htaccess I have:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|ftp|mail)\.mywebsite\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /s_%1/$1 [L]
```

Are there any other settings, or is somethig I have missed?

PS. - I don't have access to http.conf. I have to do it using only .htaccess

Thanks!

Comment: Is the redirect ignored or do you get some kind of error message?

Comment: @nhnb: I get 'Page Not found' message. I am trying to access test.mywebsite.com. I have created the folder s_test on public_html and I have added an index.html file there. So if I type http://www.mywebsite.com/s_test it is working.

Comment: are you sure that requests going to `anysubdomain.mywebsite.com` are being processed by your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @João: How to check this? Other redirects are working (eg. RewriteEngine on, RewriteRule (.*) stackoverflow.com [R] as Martin Schapendonk suggested).

Comment: In your comment I did not understand if you tested the rewrite rule by going to the address `http://www.mywebsite.com/` and `http://anothersubdomain.mywebsite.com` if you tried both it should be working, if it did not work you should re-check your dns settings. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a "plain" rewrite (the browser won't see it). To redirect, add the R flag to your RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule (.*) /s_%1/$1 [L,R]
```

The rest seems right, although I haven't tested it. For debugging you could consider RewriteLog, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: Still it doesn't work. The RewriteLog cannot be used, as I don't have access to server config. Maybe there are other settings to be applied in .htaccess, or maybe is a server configuration in http.conf that forbids me to do this.

Comment: Yes, your server administrator might have disabled mod_rewrite. You could confirm that with a simple .htaccess: RewriteEngine on, RewriteRule (.*) http://stackoverflow.com/ [R], should redirect all requests.

Comment: I have putted this rule, and it worked ok. It is redirecting me. So this means mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Use a full URL in your RewriteRule, e.g. http://www.mywebsite.com/s_%1/$1 , otherwise the (wrong subdomain) HTTP_HOST will be prepended. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I have also tried with a full URL but the same. For example, when I checked if RewriteEngine is on, like you suggested, initialy I had an error that home/user/public_html/stackoverflow.com does not exists. Now I have page not found.

Comment: Check if the http:// is there. Stackoverflow is intelligent about URL's in comments. the h t t p : / / w w w . is eaten by this intelligence :-)

Comment: Yes, I have it like this: RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/s_%1/$1 [L,R] and still doesn't work :(.

Answer (score 1):

So, neither solution does work? Try something simple then.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ${SERVER_NAME} ^(subdomain)\.yoursite\.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yoursite.com/s_%1/$1 [L,R]
```

To test if your subdomain is handled correctly, create random.html file, place it where it should be read from, and try opening it via `http://subdomain.yoursite.com/random.html`. Then you can try some stuff like:

```
RewriteRule ^random.html - [F]
```

...and if that blocks access to file, try prepending

```
RewriteCond ${SERVER_NAME} ^subdomain\.yoursite\.com$ [nc]
```

to previous rule, to block access to that file, to make sure that rewrite engine is actually hitting your rules. That would target only desired subdomain (www.yoursite.com/random.html should work, but access via subdomain shouldn't).

Then if those rules work, it's just a matter of adding more stuff and see when it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRules are a bitch.

The following should work:

**.htaccess**:

```
RewriteCond ${SERVER_NAME} !^(www|ftp|mail)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond ${SERVER_NAME} !^([^.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule .* redirect.php?to=%1
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php
   $desired_server_name = 'http://example.com';
   $subdir = 's_' . $_GET['to'];

   $url = $desired_server_name . '/' . $to . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Permanent redirects
   header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');

// Or simple redirects:
   header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');

   header('Location: '.$url);
?>
```

Works on my server (debian 4/apache 2).

Bonus: do not EVER use HTTP_HOST! See the following request:

```
 HTTP/1.1 GET /foo/bar.php
 Host: www.host.tld"><script>alert(/Hello/)</script
 Connection: close
```

If you use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in your .php scripts to construct links or .htaccess rules for that matter and "www.host.tld" is the virtual-host or the only host configured for Apache, the XSS in the HTTP request header will be passed down unescaped.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar thing working on our Virtual Machines, where we redirect anything.usertld to a folder for that domain, that was in httpd.conf, tried in in the .htaccess and like yours it didn't work.

Tweaking it, this works for me (my VM occupies a tld called benb, but changing it to your domain should be fine):

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.benb
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.benb
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/{0,1}s_
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ s_%1/$1 [L]
```

Also this captures all the text before the domain.. you should be able to change:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.benb
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.benb
```

to handle just 1 level of subdomain.  Also your other part about (www|ftp|mail) would work fine too.